# protect specific words, delete letters from string

Tags: regex, string, r

I would like to delete letters from a string, but protect specific words.  Here is an example:

```
my.string <- "Water the 12 gold marigolds please, but not the 45 trees!"

desired.result <- "12 marigolds, 45 trees"
```

I tried the code below, which gave a surprising result.  I thought `()` would protect whatever it contained.  Instead, just the opposite happened.  Only the words within `()` were deleted (plus the `!`).

```
gsub("(marigolds|trees)\\D", "", my.string)

# [1] "Water the 12 gold please, but not the 45 "
```

Here is an example with a longer string:

```
my.string <- "Water the 12 gold marigolds please, but not the 45 trees!, The 7 orange marigolds are fine."

desired.result <- "12 marigolds, 45 trees, 7 marigolds"

gsub("(marigolds|trees)\\D", "", my.string)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "Water the 12 gold please, but not the 45 , The 7 orange are fine."
```

Thank you for any advice.  I prefer a `regex` solution in base `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An other way with a capturing group:

```
my.string <- "Water the 12 gold marigolds please, but not the 45 trees!, The 7 orange marigolds are fine."
gsub("(?i)\\b(?:(marigolds|trees)|[a-z]+)\\b\\s*|[.?!]", "\\1", my.string, perl=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 7):

Using word boundary, negative look-ahead assertion.

```
> my.string <- "Water the 12 gold marigolds please, but not the 45 trees!"
> gsub("\\b(?!marigolds\\b|trees\\b)[A-Za-z]+\\s*", "", my.string, perl=TRUE)
[1] "12 marigolds , 45 trees!"
> gsub("\\b(?!marigolds\\b|trees\\b)[A-Za-z]+\\s*|!", "", my.string, perl=TRUE)
[1] "12 marigolds , 45 trees"
```

Comment: Thank you.  How would I modify this to delete the last dot in the second example?

Comment: I think this does it: `gsub("\\b(?!marigolds\\b|trees\\b)[A-Za-z]+\\s*|[!.]", "", my.string, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: @MarkMiller, Ah. I missed that.

Comment: If you want, you can add it in and I will delete my comments.

Comment: @MarkMiller, Adding `[.]` causes horizontal scrollbar appear. I will leave it as is.